# Finding Closest before and after time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table;

```
CalibrationID |     EndCalTime
     1        | 2013-12-20 08:11:13
     2        | 2013-12-20 08:13:30
     3        | 2013-12-20 08:15:26
```

etc., etc.

Now, given a DateTime `dt`, I want to be able to find the closest `EndCalTime` before and after `dt`. In MSSQL, I could just do something like `SELECT CalibrationID, MIN(timediff) FROM CalTable` and get the expected results.

In MySQL however, that doesn't seem to be the case. This query;
`SELECT CalibrationID, MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(@StabTime, EndCalTime))) FROM CPCalibrations WHERE EndCalTime < @StabTime;` always gives me an ID of 1, even though I know the ID to be 7.

Could someone please help suggest a way that will give me the desired results?

Comment: That MSSQL sample you provide will most certainly not work since it's missing a `GROUP BY` clause - which is incidentally also the exact reason MySQL is giving 'random' results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT CalibrationID, EndCalTime
FROM CPCalibrations
WHERE EndCalTime < @StabTime
ORDER BY EndCalTime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Of course! Didn't think of just doing it that way! Nice one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the closest that is either before or after:

```
select c.*
from CPCalibrations c
order by abs(timestampdiff(MICROSECOND, EndCalTime, @StabTime))
limit 1;
```

If you want the closest before and closest after (as two rows):

```
(select c.*
 from CPCalibrations c
 where EndCalTime < @StabTime
 order by EndCalTime desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select c.*
 from CPCalibrations c
 where EndCalTime > @StabTime
 order by EndCalTime asc
 limit 1
)
```

Comment: I like the first query, it's unique and simple. Doesn't quite fit the bill for me though as I need both. The second query is just a union of InoS's answer and since they answered first I'm going to accept theirs. Thanks though.